# $(T+H+I+N+K)^3 = THINK$ alfanumeric equation problem

Tags: puzzle

> There is an alfanumeric equation $$(T+H+I+N+K)^3 = THINK$$ What is $K$
>   that will be the right answer based on that equation?

The answer will be one of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. but I don't know how to start it.
Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: $$(1+9+6+8+\color{red}{3})^3 = 1968\color{red}{3}$$ can be found by brute force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to start: The five digit perfect cubes begin with $22^3$ and end with $46^3$.  However, not all of them have distinct digits...

Comment: We also have a constraint $\!\!\!\pmod{9}$ which simplifies such sieve.

Comment: There's only 24 numbers, no need for much sieving. :-)

Comment: (+1) But $24\mapsto 7$ (we just need to test $26,27,28,35,36,37,44$) still is an improvement ;)

Comment: And ............. 27 works  and so does 26.

Comment: We also don't need to test past $35=9+8+7+6+5$.